# JOptionPane Not Displaying

Tags: java, jframe, javafx-8, joptionpane

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class test extends Application {

public static String listHeader = String.format("%-20s %-20s %3s %-5s %-9s", "First Name", "Last Name", "Age", "Major", "ID Number");
public static String list = "Matthew              Name                  19 CS    12345678\n" +
        "Aaron                Name               21 CS    87654321\n" +
        "Aubree               Name                 20 BUS   83765423\n" +
        "Maddy                Name              20 BUS   93876452\n" +
        "Corbin               Name                 20 CS    93867265\n" +
        "Trystan              Name                  20 CS    73982456\n" +
        "Kiefer               Name                  20 CS    12348765 ";

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Directory list");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
            listHeader + "\n" + list,
            "Directory Listing",
            JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}

// public static void main(String argc[])
// {
//     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Directory list");
//     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
//             listHeader + "\n" + list,
//             "Directory Listing",
//             JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
// }
}
```

This is small test program I wrote. I am new to java so forgive me if this is a simple mistake. Anyways I can't seem to get the JOptionPane to display using the above code. I believe I have narrowed the problem down to the type of program. When I run my program with "extends Application" instead of a main method the code gets the JOptionPane and then does nothing. It just runs my program forever and doesn't display the JOptionPane. I have read almost all the javadocs related to JOptionPane and still have failed to come up with a solution. I did come across someone with the similar problem and it was suggested that it had to do something Swing and it's single threaded rule. Although I must admit that I don't know what that means. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:
I'm sorry I wasn't clear the first time around. The snippet of you see here is my actual program, it's just something I wrote to find the root of the problem. As I thought it has to do with me trying to mix JavaFX and Swing, and the reason I tried mixing them was I thought JOptionPane would be easy to format, and I need to use other JavaFX dialog boxes. So I guess my new question is: Is it practical to try and mix the two? or should I just stick to the Alert Dialog from JavaFX

Comment: `JFrame` and `JOptionPane` are Swing components and you're using them inside an FX `Application`. Although you can mix Swing and JavaFX you show no reason to do so. I would pick one of them and start from point 0 of learning it.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't my actual program. In my assignment, I have to use other JavaFX dialog boxes. I'm trying to use Swing because it seemed easy to format them, however I can just stick to the JavaFX Alert dialog box if I have too

Comment: If you do mix Swing and JavaFX, which you should only do if you have really good reason to do so, you need to manage the threads correctly. The `start()` method is executed on the FX Application Thread, and you can only create and display a `JOptionPane` on the AWT event dispatch thread. So you would, at a minimum, need to wrap the call to `JOptionPane.showMessage(...)` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. Note then, that the `start(...)` method execution would not be blocked until the `JOptionPane` is dismissed, so you would have to build in any synchronization you needed by hand.

Comment: @James_D okay, didn't know about that one. removed the unnecessary comment

Comment: Stick with JavaFX and when you write the `Application` class properly and whatever it is doesn't work *then* ask about that with the proper code.